# Powershell command to list nearby bluetooth devices and connect to one of them in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, powershell, bluetooth

When we go to
**settings->PC and devices->Bluetooth** and then if we turn on the bluetooth then it displays all near by bluetooth devices.

```
I am curious how could we do this through powershell.

And after that I want the powershell command to connect to one of those listed devices.
```

I am using windows **8.1** and my powershell version is **4.0**

Thanks in advance geeks.

Comment: [What have you searched for?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+connect+to+bluetooth+device%27&t=h_&ia=web)  What have you Tried? What errors did you encounter? Post your code?  SU rules: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) ---  [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I found for listing wifi devices using this command netsh wlan  show network  mode=bssid . Like that I want to list all near by bluetooth devices